# FXMLLoader template flag

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Looking at [`FXMLLoader#load`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--), a "template flag" is mentioned - yet I see no explanation of how to set this flag. Presumably there should be a `FXMLLoader#setTemplate`, but no such method exists in the linked JavaDoc, and using the latest 1.8 OpenJDK (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b05) I can't see such method either.

So what is this flag, and how do I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [some discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-September/010430.html) on the JavaFX developer list about creating this flag in order to generate a better-performing mode for loading FXML files for certain use cases. It [seems this idea was not included](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-October/010636.html) in the final release of JavaFX 8.0, but clearly the API documentation didn't fully reflect that decision.

So the actual answer to your question is that the API documentation is wrong: there is no such flag.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way of making subsequent `load` calls faster, other than implementing my own `ClassLoader`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Loading a scene graph from FXML is inherently quite slow (file or resource I/O and lots of reflection). Tom Schindl suggested the idea of [compiling FXML to Java classes](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/08/29/convert-fxml-to-java-as-part-of-the-build/) as part of the build process, though I don't know how far this project went. I think I'd recommend just building anything where performance of initialization is important directly in Java, rather than FXML, though I understand the constraints on productivity that advice might impose.